# Wordpress category search

Tags: wordpress, search

In wordpress:
I need to search only the categories names and not the content.

For instance:

Post 1 (category Dog)
"i am a dog and not cat"

Post 2 (category Cat)
"I am a cat and not a dog"

Search Query "Dog" will show only post1 (and not post2 which contains that word Dog)

(Solution can be a code or some Wordpress Search plugin)

Comment: Try this plugin, it states "You can search by Category, Tag, Custom Taxonomy, Post Type, Post Date or any combination of these" https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/

Comment: no..i need  that the simple Search query box will search  only the categories and not dropdowns.

Comment: if user write the text "do" and search what should be happen

Comment: "do" will give no results (because there is no category "do").
Dog will give post1  - and not post2.

Comment: You'll need to write some custom code using the pre_get_posts filter.  You can read up about it here https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Answer (score 1):

If you need standalone search script for using inside some function, then you need a solution like this

```
$search_query='dog';$allcats=array();
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array('hide_empty' => false));
foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value->name,$search_query)!==false) $allcats[]=$value->term_id;
}

$foundposts=get_posts(array("post_type"=>"post","category__in"=>$allcats));
foreach ($foundposts as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->title.'<br>';
}
```

But if you mean to change global search results, then you need to change pre_get_posts rules.
For example,

```
function onlycatsearch ($query) {
if ($query->is_search and is_admin() and !empty($_GET["s"])) {

$search_query=get_search_query();
$allcats=array();
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array('hide_empty' => false));
foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value->name,$search_query)!==false) $allcats[]=$value->term_id;
}

$query->set('s', "");
$query->set('category__in', $allcats);
}

}

add_action('pre_get_posts','onlycatsearch');
```